# Compare loaded scene error c# unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Compare loaded scene error c# unity
Hi i try to make a script to compare what scene is play, i am new on scripting,
and it give an error: 
unexpected symbol '=' in  class,struct or interface member declaration
and 
unexpected simbol 'if' in class, struct or iterface member declaration
this is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class levelverify : MonoBehaviour {
        if(Application.loadedLevelName = "level_1"){
            ScoreSystem.level = 1;
        }
}
```

Comment: Is this problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

You compare with multiple `==` sign not one.

```
if (Application.loadedLevelName == "level_1")
{
}
```

Also, [`Application.loadedLevelName`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-loadedLevelName.html) is now deprecated. You have to use [`SceneManager`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.html):

```
if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "level_1")
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with 'if', 'for', and 'while' statements you will need two equals. '==' because '=' is for setting values & '==' is for checking values

Example:

```
if (name == "this") {
     //Do this
}
```